# Accessing a file from a Unit Test Bundle with Xcode 3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do you access a file to use in unit tests? (Every time I have asked with more specific information I cannot get ANYONE to answer.)

Comment: You clearly need more information in order to get a good answer.  Do you mean access a file in your Resources folder (part of the bundle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?
  If you are trying to dump a data file and re-read it:

```
// To Dump:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);   
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyDataFile"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:mediaManager toFile:filePath];

// To Re-Load:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyDataFile"];

myReciever = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath] retain];
```